# PHP OOP: how should I declare my component properties

Tags: php

I'm learning OOP a little and I want to get myself some good habits.
I'm writing an app which uses 'components'. 
Each component is being included in component View, when $_GET['component_name'] is proper.
Components are placed in /components/component_name/ and contains files like index.php, helper.php, controller.php.
I'm doing index.php this way:

```
$name = "newsModule";
$helper = $name."Helper";
global $component;
$component = new $name;

$component->name = $name;
$component->template = 1;
$component->prefix = "com_";
$component->legend = array(
      "time" => "create date",
      "edit" => "edit",
      "remove" => "delete"
);
$component->db = $component->prefix.$name;
$component->id = $_GET['id'];
$component->itemList = $helper::itemList(array(
      'fields' => '*',
  'db' => $component->db,
  'where-field' => "title",
  'where-value' => $_SESSION['keywords_'.$name]
));
```

Now, the $component is visible in Component View in $GLOBALS array, so I do:

```
$c = $GLOBALS['component'];
```

and using $c->db for example. And it works.
But finally - what's my point? I just think this solution is not good enough, no-oop enough etc.
I wonder if someone could share some good practices, some info and ideas about how could this code be better.
Thank you

Comment: Apart from the technical detail that you're using objects, nothing about this code is "OOP". I'm not sure where to start correcting this. You should start with reading about and understanding S.O.L.I.D. principles.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links for a good solid introduction to OOP in php.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm

And as for good habits, find a good working example that more or less does what you want and tweak it to your needs. If you write from scratch you'll quite likely fall flat on your face at every opportunity (speaking from experience).